# Navigate to another page from highcharts ChartClickEvent using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using dotnet.highcharts with ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have two working pieces.

I have a working chart and a working page at signup/signup.

I want the signup/signup page to show when I click on the body of the chart.

The chart

```
   Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart
            {
                DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column,
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                Events = new ChartEvents { Click = "ChartClickEvent" }
            })
            .AddJavascripFunction("ChartClickEvent", @"$.get('signup/signup')")
            .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Sign ups" })
            ......
```

The ChartClickEvent is working. The server side controller and view code is executed when I click on the chart. I can step through it. The browser does not display the signup page however.

I feel I am missing something simple.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: OK - seems like using  window.location = "signup/signup" sorted out my issue.